# Mechanize browser.submit() returning the original form instead of the expected result

Tags: python, mechanize, scrape

When I submit a form to the Health Canada website, I am getting a return of the original form:

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser


def run():
    browser = Browser()
    browser.open("https://health-products.canada.ca/dpd-bdpp/index-eng.jsp")

    browser.select_form("search")
    browser['status'] = 0
    browser['brandName'] = "Stelara"

    response = browser.submit()

    content = response.read()    

    print content
```

I get a status of 200 from the response, implying that it was successful, but then I print the content returned it's just the original form.

What I am trying to figure out now is why the response is different for me when I manually submit the form as opposed to when I submit it with mechanize.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `browser.form['field'] = value` instead of `browser['field'] = value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - I was passing an integer where it wanted a list

```
browser['status'] = 0
```

became

```
browser['status'] = ['0',]
```